# Different performance for one creating data task in Spring Boot, Postgres

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I tried to reload data after creating it, but reloading task takes it too long when comparing with creating.

Performance:
CSV file: 1,2k records.
Insert data into table for the first time: 15.413022393 seconds
Then, I delete all data: 1.196959342 Seconds
Then, I insert data into table for the second time with same function, same csv file:  52.934162753 Seconds

Summary: 1st time: 15.4 seconds, 2nd time: 52.9 seconds.
When I change csv file with 66k records, I get the bitter result:
1st time: 15 mins, 2nd time: around 2 hours.

Do you know why it takes too different performance for the same task? And what should I do to get the performance in the 2nd time as same as the 1st time.

Here is my source code:

```
public class EtlApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
public static boolean acessDB = true;

@Autowired
ProcessDataController processDataController;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(EtlApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    acessDB = false;
    processDataController.createData();
    acessDB = true;
}
```

}

ProcessData and test

```
public class ProcessDataController {
public static final String CSV_URL = "C:\\abc.csv";
List<CSVSales> data = new ArrayList<>();
@Autowired
private ARepository aRepository;

@Autowired
private BRepository bRepository;

@Autowired
private CRepository cRepository;

@Autowired
private DRepository dRepository;

@Autowired
private ERepository eRepository;

@Autowired
private FRepository fRepository;

@Autowired
private GRepository gRepository;

@Autowired
private HRepository hRepository;

@Autowired
private IRepository iRepository;

@Autowired
private KRepository kRepository;

@Autowired
private LRepository lRepository;

public void createData() throws IOException, ParseException {
    // BEGIN - For TESTING
    long step[] = new long[20];
    double timer[] = new double[20];
    ArrayList<String> table = new ArrayList<>();
    table.add("A");
    table.add("B");
    table.add("C");
    table.add("D");
    table.add("E");
    table.add("F");
    table.add("G");
    table.add("H");
    table.add("I");
    table.add("K");
    table.add("L");
    // END - For TESTING

    CSVReadAndParse readAndParse = new CSVReadAndParse();
    readAndParse.setUrl(CSV_URL);

    step[0] = System.nanoTime();
    data = readAndParse.getResult();
    step[1] = System.nanoTime();
    timer[0] = step[1] - step[0];

    for (int num = 0; num < data.size(); num++) {
        step[0] = System.nanoTime();
        A a = new A(data.get(num).getACode(), data.get(num).getAName());
        aRepository.save(a);
        step[1] = System.nanoTime();
        timer[1] += step[1] - step[0];


        B b = new B(data.get(num).getBCode(), data.get(num).getBName());
        bRepository.save(b);
        step[2] = System.nanoTime();
        timer[2] += step[2] - step[1];

        C c = new C(data.get(num).getC());
        cRepository.save(c);
        step[3] = System.nanoTime();
        timer[3] += step[3] - step[2];

        D d = new D(data.get(num).getDCode(), data.get(num).getDName());
        dRepository.save(d);
        step[4] = System.nanoTime();
        timer[4] += step[4] - step[3];

        E e = new E(data.get(num).getECode(), data.get(num).getEName());
        eRepository.save(e);
        step[5] = System.nanoTime();
        timer[5] += step[5] - step[4];

        F f = new F(data.get(num).getF());
        fRepository.save(month);
        step[6] = System.nanoTime();
        timer[6] += step[6] - step[5];

        G g = new G(data.get(num).getGCode(), data.get(num).getGName());
        gRepository.save(g);
        step[7] = System.nanoTime();
        timer[7] += step[7] - step[6];

        H h = new H(data.get(num).getHCode(), data.get(num).getHName());
        pRepository.save(h);
        step[8] = System.nanoTime();
        timer[8] += step[8] - step[7];

        I i = new I(data.get(num).getICode(), data.get(num).getIName());
        iRepository.save(i);
        step[9] = System.nanoTime();
        timer[9] += step[9] - step[8];

        K k = new K(data.get(num).getK());
        kRepository.save(k);
        step[10] = System.nanoTime();
        timer[10] += step[10] - step[9];


        L l = new L();
        L.setA(data.get(num).getNumberOfSale());
        L.setB(data.get(num).getSalesAmount());
        l.setC(a);
        l.setC(b);
        l.setD(c);
        l.setE(d);
        l.setF(e);
        l.setG(f);
        l.setH(g);
        l.setI(h);
        l.setK(i);
        fRepository.save(l);
        step[11] = System.nanoTime();
        timer[11] += step[11] - step[10];
    }
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 11; i++) {
        System.out.println(table.get(i - 1) + " time: " + new DecimalFormat("#.##########").format(timer[i] / 1000000000) + " seconds");
        sum += timer[i];
    }
    System.out.println("Reading data time: " + new DecimalFormat("#.##########").format(timer[0] / 1000000000) + " seconds");
    System.out.println("Total creating table time: " + new DecimalFormat("#.##########").format(sum / 1000000000) + " seconds");
}
public void deleteAllData() {
    lRepository.deleteAll();
    aRepository.deleteAll();
    bRepository.deleteAll();
    cRepository.deleteAll();
    eRepository.deleteAll();
    fRepository.deleteAll();
    gRepository.deleteAll();
    hRepository.deleteAll();
    iRepository.deleteAll();
    kRepository.deleteAll();
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/reloadData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public  String reloadData() throws IOException, ParseException {
    System.out.println("------------------------" + acessDB);
    if (acessDB) {
        acessDB = false;
        long step1 = System.nanoTime();
        deleteAllData();
        long step2 = System.nanoTime();
        createData();
        long step3 = System.nanoTime();
        double time1 = ((double) (step2 - step1) / 1000000000);
        double time2 = ((double) (step3 - step2) / 1000000000);
        double time3 = ((double) (step3 - step1) / 1000000000);
        System.out.println("Delete time: " + new DecimalFormat("#.##########").format(time1) + " Seconds");
        System.out.println("Create time: " + new DecimalFormat("#.##########").format(time2) + " Seconds");
        System.out.println("Total time: " + new DecimalFormat("#.##########").format(time3) + " Seconds");
        acessDB = true;
        return "Done";
    } else {
        return "Busy";
    }
}
```

}

If you have any idea, please help me. Thank you all for your support.

---

### result for 1,2k records

### 1st time

A time: 1.447862537 seconds

Btime: 1.255404293 seconds

Ctime: 1.394218887 seconds

D time: 1.187494522 seconds

E time: 1.181336583 seconds

F time: 1.259357541 seconds

G time: 1.2722146 seconds

H time: 1.276657592 seconds

I time: 1.238350482 seconds

K time: 1.132834423 seconds

L time: 2.767290933 seconds

Reading data time: 0.017714579 seconds

Total creating table time: 15.413022393 seconds

---

### 2nd time

A time: 4.452199036 seconds

B time: 4.602505654 seconds

C time: 4.847908167 seconds

D time: 4.424638278 seconds

E time: 4.820910787 seconds

F time: 5.235425021 seconds

G time: 5.069998945 seconds

H time: 5.022227053 seconds

I time: 4.918734423 seconds

K time: 4.483681708 seconds

L time: 5.04199453 seconds

Reading data time: 0.008831614 seconds

Total creating table time: 52.920223602 seconds

Delete time: 1.196959342 Seconds

Create time: 52.934162753 Seconds

Total time: 54.131122095 Seconds

Comment: Usually batch operation with hibernate requires you to clear session cache every n iterations like explained in https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html

Comment: Just for reference, double digit seconds count for thousands of rows is ... acceptable only on 20 year old machines. That is a HUGE overhead you have there.
Just for fun, try loading CSV data using the Postgresql `COPY` command. Depending on row size, machine, etc, it's usually hundreds of thousands per second. Like right now I'm moving some data from gzipped CSVs, and it will take me around 20-30 minutes for 100 million rows at around 0.3KB/row.

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci Thanks for your support. I personally think that my problem comes from batch process. But in my implementation, I don't use hibernate for committing transaction, I only use a loop of save() function in CrudRepository.
I haved try add EntityManager.refresh to all Spring Data Repositories but failed. https://www.javabullets.com/add-entitymanager-refresh-spring-data-repositories/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before save entity, I tried to autewired Entity Manager by:

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Then, instead of using save functions, use saveAndFlush functions.

After that, using `entityManager.clear();`